# How to get the index value of column value compared with another column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want something like this.

```
Index    Sentence
0           I
1           want
2           like 
3           this

Keyword     Index
 want        1
 this        3
```

I tried with `df.index("Keyword")` but its not giving for all the rows. It will be really helpful if someone solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) only:

```
df = df[df['Sentence'].isin(['want', 'this'])]
print (df)
   Index Sentence
1      1     want
3      3     this
```

EDIT: If need compare by another column:

```
df = df[df['Sentence'].isin(df['Keyword'])]
#another DataFrame df2
#df = df[df['Sentence'].isin(df2['Keyword'])]
```

And if need index values:

```
idx = df.index[df['Sentence'].isin(df['Keyword'])]
#alternative
#idx = df[df['Sentence'].isin(df['Keyword'])].index
```

Comment: I should get the index value based on column name "Keyword" not based on value inside "Keyword" column

Comment: That's brilliant. But I am not getting the first word's index.For example.,     `Index  Sentence
      3     this `     like  this i'm getting